# how to change other element css when selected element has new class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is that possible to change other element `css` when element has selected. For example the code bellow have `div.allgametap_wrapper` , inside have `div.allgame_tabitem`,`div.clear` and `div.tabtitle` . What I mean is I have using js to switch the class `selected` inside `div.allgame_tabitem` , when `div.allgame_tabitem` has class `selected` the `div.tabtitle` inside it self `div.allgametap_wrapper` will change to `css #fff (white)`.

```
<div class="allgametap_wrapper">
    <div class="allgame_tabitem onlinegametab"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="tabtitle" style="color:#666;"></div>
</div>
<div class="allgametap_wrapper">
    <div class="allgame_tabitem allgametab selected"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="tabtitle" style="color:#666;"></div>
</div>
```

**JS Switch Selected Code**

```
    $(".allgame_tab_container div div.allgame_tabitem").on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var $this = $(this);
       $(".allgame_tab_container div div.allgame_tabitem").removeClass('selected');
       $this.addClass('selected');
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great If you can provide the js code of yours. Here is the illustration :

```
// $(this) would refer to current selected element
// this depend on your existed js code
if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
  $('.tabtitle').css('color','#666'); //<-- add this
  $(this).siblings('.tabtitle').css('color','#fff');
}
```

Comment: hi this work ~ but everyone I click is white , how if when element is not `selected` return to color `#666` back ?

Answer (score 1):

here is shorthand code for that

```
 $("div.allgame_tabitem").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

         $(this).siblings('.tabtitle').css('color', '#fff');
     } else {

         $(this).addClass('selected');
         $(this).siblings('.tabtitle').css('color', '#fff');
         $(this).parent().siblings().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
     }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to:

```
window.document.getElementByClassName("allgametap_wrapper").style.color = white;
```

A bit tricky to understand what you mean.